# How to update my WSUS server content folder manually

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus, wsus-offline

I have a WSUS Server on a virtualized Windows Server 2008 R2. My server its not connected to the internet directly so I use a upstream corporative server for the updates download. This other server its connected with windows update service. First of all when I tried to sync my WSUS server with the corporative one I only achieve a 16% of sycn and that means more than 11000 patches. My internet connection is very slow .. only 1 Mbps for all corporative services ... email ... internet ... chat. So I figured that I could ask the network administrator of the WSUS server connected to windows update for his wsuscontent folder. It weights around 300 GB. Impossible for me to download. Can I just copy/replace my wsuscontent folder or do I need to do another thing? And the other thing is: Can I do the same with the sync? There is some file I can copy and replace in my server in order to just update the latest entries in this catalog. I don't know if I explained the problem clearly enough feel free to ask me anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use the word "corporative" do you mean "co-operative", which means "working together", or "corporate" which relates to a business?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see this link: [How to Synchronize Updates Using Export and Import](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680473.aspx)

While it is technically talking about SCCM and WSUS, it will still work with just a WSUS server.

After it is synced, you can then point your downstream WSUS server to the parent to stay in sync going forward.

Be aware though that your 1Mbps bottleneck may mean that you would be better off just managing approvals from WSUS and configuring it to have the clients pull from Windows Update for the actual downloads.

Comment: *managing approvals from WSUS and configuring it to have the clients pull from Windows Update*...Actually, one step better would be to configure the WSUS server to [download only approved updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708460(v=ws.10).aspx), in which case they're only transferred once over your 1 Mbps pipe instead of once per client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply my friends ... i was beginning to think that no one will answer me ... i have posted this question in numerous forums ...

Comment: Twisty ... i exactly did as you say ... i only donwload approved updates ... i have 4 categories of automatic approval ... windows Xp .. windows 7 ... windows 7 ... and server 2008 R2 ... i will keep you posted about my progress thanks for everything

Comment: @Twisty - while true I figured it was possible the OP's client base was outside the norm with mainly remote users.  Maybe I read into it wrong.

Comment: @TheCleaner I assumed that because the OP mentioned he is constrained by a [solitary, by my reading] 1 mbps pipe, all the clients were behind that link and therefore not roaming devices.

Comment: @Twisty - yep I can conclude that today as well.  which means your comment is definitely the way to go here on the config options.

Comment: @TheCleaner I'll consider that a proposed edit to your question then.

Comment: The config options are really an addendum to the actual answer to the OP's question, but definitely feel free to edit my answer.